# Learning ASP.NET MVC start with 1 or 2 or 3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC world. I have enough experience for ASP.NET 2.0 and 3.5.

But as I'm seeing that we are now at Version 4, it is making me feel uncomfortable to directly start with this latest version. I'm browsing through [ASP.NET MVC video tutorials](http://www.asp.net/mvc/videos) at microsoft website which is listing learning series starting with ASP.NET MVC  -1, MVC -2, MVC -3 and even MVC - 4.

So now the confusion comes here..!! If I start with MVC -3 directly.. did I missed something by ignoring MVC - 1 and MVC - 2 ?

Can I directly start with MVC - 3? without worrying about anything else.

Comment: Thank you all for the kind information. Upvoted everyone.. but accepted the best answer..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should definitely not go back to 1 or 2, things have changed quite significantly since then. You don't want to spend too much time in learning things that's not applicable any more. I will recommend you to start with the Book "Pro ASP.NET MVC 3 Framework", that's how I learnt my MVC.

The book starts with a simple example on how MVC works and goes in detail for each individual features of MVC used. If you master the book, you master the MVC!

Answer (score 2):

Don't worry at all about the versions of asp.net mvc at the time of learning. Major concepts in mvc framework are `Model, View, Controller, Routes` and once you have basic understand of them you will be able to work with any of the version.

All basic features stated above works same in all versions but different versions added some more capabilities. One of the example for mvc3 compared to mvc4 is the mobile views.

So, don't hesitate and get started!

Comment: Quite possibly the best response I have ever read on S/O. Thanks @Prashant Lakhlani

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend starting with at least Mvc3 and to even consider using Mvc4.

The newer releases tend to be supersets and improvements on previous releases.

The only reason not to go with Mvc4 is that there may be more current training material with Mvc3.  That said I think there is already plenty on Mvc4.

Answer (score 1):

You won't miss a thing if you start at MVC3 (or 4), I would even recommend it. And start at looking at Razor-views immediately, that's the view-language you'd want to use.